# Design of Enemy class using sf::Sound object to be played

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm struggling with design of my game in SFML, and I wonder what's the best approach in this case. So let's say we have an `Enemy` class, which has an update method. It's being called every loop of the game loop (I will paste only the important part of it):

```
void Enemy::update()
{
    if (state == State::DESTROYED) {
        sound.play();
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(2*16, 0, 26, 16));
        while (sound.getStatus() != sf::Sound::Status::Stopped);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, the state of the `Enemy` class' object is being updated from another method which calls `setState` method from `Enemy` class, and sets the Enemy to be destroyed (game loop will check the vector of enemies in the next iteration and if any enemy has state set to be destroyed, it will get erased from the vector). There's one thing that's a problem for me (if not the above mentioned design is already a problem). Whenever I want to play a sound of death, in the next fragment of the game loop the `Enemy` object is being destroyed, thus the sound can't play fully and `Enemy` object needs to wait - I've solved this by making a busy-waiting loop which basically waits for the sound to be stopped (waiting for it to be fully played), although this introduces a lag when `Enemy` is being killed.

Now my question is - what's a good approach/approaches to the design in this case? I've came with an idea to create a SoundManager class, and pass a reference to `sf::Sound` object in `Enemy`'s class constructor, and it would basically hold a reference to the original object inside the `Enemy` class (as a member of it), whereas the lifetime of `sf::Sound` object would be prolonged because it would come from outside the `Enemy` class. At the same time busy-wait loop will not be needed. I don't know why, but for some reason this design feels like a bad idea for me, or is it not?

Maybe the sound being played should be inside the game loop, not in the object's method?

Comment: You could have an intermediate "destroying" state that the enemy is in while it's dying, and in that state you can just check every frame if the sound has finished playing.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel amazing yet simple idea, thank you. One more thing - do you think it would be good to hold the reference to the sf::Sound (which would be managed by SoundManager class) inside Enemy class anyways, or is it good as it is now?

Comment: If you feel like you can correctly track the lifetime of those objects without ever ending up with a dangling reference, I guess.